# Get pc-intervall of the receiver of a method

Tags: java, javassist

For a project I have to get java bytecode information (static analysis) of a method receiver : 
e.g. ***x***.method(); .

If the method takes some arguments we can't separate the receiver from the arguments at bytecode-level, 
e.g. ***x***.method(**arg1**, **arg2**, ...);.

In bytecode first the receiver is loaded, then the arguments and at the end there is the opcode "invoke.*". It would look like this

> pc0 - pc? (receiver)
> pc? - pc88 (arguments; 88 is just an example)
> pc89 (invoke.*)
> -> want to find out "?"

In other words, how can I get the pc-intervall of the receiver?
I looked at Javassist, but the class MethodCall does not provide anything in this diretion.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I am not clear on what you are looking for. Can you give a better example, starting with a static method Class.Method ?

Comment: "We can't separate the object reference from the arguments" Umm.... What? I googled "javassist pc" and all that comes up is LineNumberTable data. Can you elaborate a little more on what you're trying to look at?

Comment: @Nichloas&@DankVader, I edited the question. Hope it is more clear why I need help.